# How to make ASP.NET MVC links written in different alphabet

Tags: asp.net-mvc, seo

I have an ASP.NET MVC application and I want to make links written in Cyrillic within the application. What are possible pitfalls from the developing point of view?

To be more precise:
now the link looks like: 
    http://mysite.ru/books 
and I want to make it look like: 
    [http://mysite.ru/книги](http://mysite.ru/%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8) 
or maybe even: 
    [http://мойсайт.ру/книги](http://%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82.%D1%80%D1%83/%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8)

An the next question can I use both URLs and which will be the attitude of Google and other search engines

EDIT:
Well I wouldn't ask if it was't possible
check this out http://www.codeisart.ru/%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B2%D1%8B-%D0%B2-url-google-%D0%B8-yandex/
**Yes it look strange here but in browser the URL is written right in russian.At least on my PC.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/appendix/notes.html#h-B.2.1) URI's in non ASCII should be escaped to %D1%81 style. I have looked in html sources of ru.wikipedia.org all uri's are escaped, but there is a feature of some of the new browsers - convert this escaped uri's to UTF8 and they sometimes displays as normal cyrylic. Arguable feature.

As about MVC, I have just tried for my routing **{languageCode}/{controller}/{action}/{id}** perform something like [http://servername.com/ru/articles/show/статья1](http://servername.com/ru/articles/show/%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%8F1) and it passes to action...

```
  public ActionResult Show(String id)
```

... normal utf8 Cyrillic string in id param.

[http://мойсайт.ру/книги](http://%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82.%D1%80%D1%83/%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8)  :-)